# lambda adding to class count

Tags: java, lambda, garbage-collection, classloader

So rather quick question:

If I have a program that is using a lot of lambda expressions, is each lambda creating a new class that is stored in `metaspace`?

Normally it would be fine if it is stored there, but what if you also add the java flag `-Xnoclassgc`, would that create a leak that eventually crashes the program?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-Xnoclassgc` flag doesn't disable the whole `Garbage Collector`. It only disables the `Garbage Collector` of classes from `PermGen`.

However, in **JDK8**, we no longer have the `PermGen` because the metadata has now moved to native memory to an area known as the `Metaspace`.

On the other hand, `Lambda` expressions in Java are **instances** of **Functional Interfaces** (*a functional interface is an interface that contains exactly one abstract method*).

In other words, lambdas are **`objects`** and treated like other objects and stored on the heap, so compiler does not create `.class` file for every instance of lambda.

Comment: It might be that I simply don't understand your answer, but if `lambdas` are truly objects and treated as objects, then I should see any lambdas as loaded classes in my heap dump right? (which I do)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Under the hood they use an instruction introduced in Java 7 - [invokedynamic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html#invokedynamic)

You can watch this presentation for more information - https://www.infoq.com/presentations/lambda-invokedynamic